# Find and Replace alternative? Instead of "REPLACE", simply add text to existing cell?

Tags: excel, vba, function, replace, find

I need to sort through a product list that has over 40000 lines and some of these items have a size associated to them, yet the sku is the same for the item regardless of size. BUT, there is a seperate column for size for each item, simply put, I want to add the size, example: if an item has a column size small, I just want to add "-small" at the end of the existing SKU.

I am trying to figure out a way to "find and replace all", except I do not want to "replace"I simply want to add a certain word to existing columns, with the condition that the "size"is found.

Would I need to create a VBA for this specific application? Or a simple/existing function is available for this type of situation?

Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question with a **specific example** of the input data and the desired result.  Thia will allow us to test our answers before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with just an excel function, though you'd need to dedicate a column to your new SKU. The formula to use would be `=IF(B2<>"",CONCAT(A2,"-",B2),A2)`, where A2 is the cell with the original SKU and B2 is the cell with the size. You could of course do this with VBA as well quite easily in which case you could avoid having to add an extra column for the formatted SKU. If that's important to you, just edit your question and I can provide an example of what that would look like.

[image: SKU example]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just add the size to the SKU number, you can use vba to loop through each cell in the `SKU` column, add "-" and the value from the `Size` column. Example below. The example below uses `Col A` as the `SKU` column and `Col B` as the `Size` column, change the column numbers and worksheet as needed.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

For x = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value & "-" & ws.Cells(x, 2).Value
Next x
```